# Getting Flutter SDK by git clone

Tags: flutter

[Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows?gclid=CjwKCAjwoc_8BRAcEiwAzJevtX_XAhu-57Lr94a2kyqOGzXaLkz0qaZ-WPlkHOlACDX7ix9-TNwicxoC-FAQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#get-the-flutter-sdk) two steps are mentioned to get Flutter SDK:

1. Download the following installation bundle ...
2. Extract the zip file ...

and then it is mentioned:

> If you don’t want to install a fixed version of the installation bundle, you can skip steps 1 and > 2. Instead, get the source code from the Flutter repo on GitHub, and change branches or tags as > needed. For example:
>
> `C:\src>git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable`

I have done so:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

But when I point to cloned Git repository folder of `flutter\bin` in Android Studio, I receive this error:

> Cannot Save Settings:
> Flutter SDK is not found in the specified location.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I get Flutter SDK by Git clone?

Comment: set flutter folder as path: `C:Users\m3\repos\flutter`

Comment: @SaeedFekri Did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added to my PATH:

```
C:\Users\m3\repos\flutter\bin
```

Then I ran `flutter --version` on command line:

```
C:\Users\m3>flutter --version                                                                                                                                   Checking Dart SDK version...
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ...
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Flutter 1.24.0-4.0.pre.54 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision a7c47ddeee (9 hours ago) • 2020-10-24 17:42:02 -0400
Engine • revision 2640541dc0
Tools • Dart 2.11.0 (build 2.11.0-251.0.dev)
```

Then I ran `flutter doctor` on command line:

```
C:\Users\m3>flutter doctor
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Downloading Material fonts...                                       7.5s
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                      742ms
Downloading package sky_engine...                                   4.0s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                           29.5s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...                   28.9s
Downloading windows-x64 tools...                                   62.7s
Downloading windows-x64/font-subset tools...                        8.9s
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-4.0.pre.54, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.264], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Then I could set `C:\Users\m3\repos\flutter` as Flutter SDK path without any error:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what directory did the flutter sdk installed?